# Android - Keep ActionBar/Toolbar in front of Fragment animations

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments

I'm using `translate` animations to slide a fragment in from the bottom and out the top. During this animation, though, the `Toolbar` or `ActionBar` is sent to the back, making it look like there's some kind of glitch in the animation (the animated `Fragment` covers the `Toolbar`).

Is there a way to make sure the `Toolbar` is always shown in front of the animation? I did try setting the `:zAdjustment` to `bottom`, but that didn't change anything.

Here's one of the animations. The others are just variations of `:fromYDelta` and `:toYDelta`.

```
<set>
    <translate
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:fromYDelta="-100%"
        android:toYDelta="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        android:duration="1000"/>
</set>
```

The `FragmentTransaction`

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_bottom, R.anim.slide_out_top, R.anim.slide_in_top, R.anim.slide_out_bottom)
        .replace(R.id.master_container, getManageFragment())
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
```

This is my `activity_main.xml`

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/master_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/navigation_toolbar" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/navigation_view" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And then this layout is added to `master_container`

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/global_background"
    app:layout_behavior="com.cohenadair.anglerslog.views.FloatingButtonBehavior">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/main_recycler_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_half"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_half"
        android:clipToPadding="false"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/new_button"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_default"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/main_recycler_view"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:layout_behavior="com.cohenadair.anglerslog.utilities.ScrollingFabBehavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Thank you.

EDIT: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047868/how-to-animate-view-slide-in-from-from-below-action-bar-and-slide-out-into-bot) seems to be a similar issue.

Comment: Where have you set the `toolbar`? In `activity` or in `fragments`?

Comment: It's set in the `Activity`

Comment: If it is `activity` then transitions in `FrameLayout` shouldn't affect the `toolbar`.

Comment: Well, the `Fragment` being animated out is a `CoordinatorLayout` and switching the `Fragment` being animated in to `FrameLayout` didn't change anything.

Comment: Please provide your layout.xml

Comment: Added the relative layout files.

Answer (score 0):

If you set `Toolbar` in `Activity` then transitions in `FrameLayout` won't affect toolbar. I have tried like this & it's working

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="start">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            android:title="@string/app_name"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <include layout="@layout/navigation_drawer_layout"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

For animations:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_top, R.anim.exit_to_bottom, R.anim.enter_from_bottom, R.anim.exit_to_top)
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
                    .commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

enter_from_bottom.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="100%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="700" />
</set>
```

enter_from_top.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="-100%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="700"/>
</set>
```

exit_to_bottom.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="100%"
        android:duration="700" />
</set>
```

exit_to_top.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="-100%"
        android:duration="700"/>
</set>
```